# Does the direction of the change in magnetic flux matter in Lenz's law?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction, lenz-law

[image: A sketch of the situation]

Does the direction of the change in magnetic flux matter ?
For instance, here, the change in flux(taking  downwards to be positive) is positive if the magnetic is falling with its north-pole facing downwards. Whereas when the magntic falls with  the south-pole facing down , the change in flux is negative .Hence the first magnet should fall faster.
However, I remember reading a while back in a similar question, that they fall at the same rate(don't remember the source) why is this so. Why doesn't it matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change in flux for both situations is such that it generates a magnetic field that opposes the change in flux.

A magnet with the North Pole falling at the bottom  will have a positive change in flux, this produces a North Pole that repells the the magnetic

A magnet with the south Pole falling will have a negative change of flux, which produces a south Pole, repelling the magnet.

They experience the same amount of repulsion.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!